# ERROR: Problem encountered: Python (3.x) mako module >= 0.8.0 required to build mesa

Tags: android, android-source, mako

While Building the Android AOSP i am getting this error :

```
meson.build:1018:2: ERROR: Problem encountered: Python (3.x) mako module >= 0.8.0 required to build mesa.
```

I checked that mako is already installed with version

```
MarkupSafe>=0.9.2 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from mako) (1.1.0)
```

What could be the fix?